# Any way to auto-modify an action?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

Is there any way to auto-modify an action on Photoshop? For example, multiple workers use our internal action pack and I wanna be able to modify something without having them to replace/load the actions each time, is that possible?

Maybe a action that runs a script that runs the actions from folder? So changing the actions on folder would change the actions when they run?

So I basically found what I need http://www.tonton-pixel.com/scripts/utility-scripts/play-actions-file-action/index.html

But it opens the little screen each time asking which action I wanna play... any way to make it directly?

Answer (score 0):

You need a script for that. If you still want actions, then an *action that runs a script that runs the actions from folder* would work.

Ideally you'd abandon Actions all together and redo them as scripts (there's a script that converts actions to scripts files) and then actions may call those scripts on a server, so you can modify every step without telling people to reload .atn files.

Advantages of scripts will be:

- as I mentioned, easy to modify;
- you can have one undo for a long script (in actions 1 undo = 1 step);
- much easier to trace/fix errors;